PureData-Gem: pc camera not loaded by the [pix_video] object
I have windows 11 pro ver.22H2, using PlugData 9.2 and Gem 0.94.
I'm trying to flash the webcam video via the [pix_video] object on a rectangle, via [pix_texture]. Problem: [pix_video] throws the following errors:

"[GEM:videoVFW] Unable to set video format"
"no valid video backend found"

I've tried using an external camera, but same results.
I've tried also [this](https://forum.pdpatchrepo.info/topic/12821/pd-64-bit-cannot-start-webcam-pix_video-no-valid-video-backend-found/12#:~:text=Fast%2Dforward%20a%20couple%20of%20years%20%2D%2D%20I%20just%20had%20a%20student%20with%20exactly%20the%20same%20problem%2C%20in%20Windows%20(couldn%27t%20open%20%5Bpix_video%5D%20using%20the%20videoInput%20backend) suggested solution, but didn't work either.

the usage of VFW (instead of VIDS) hints that there's some there's some miscompilation of the Gem video backends. where did you get Gem from? via deken, or is it shipped with plugdata?

Thank you for helping. I downloaded it via the "search for externals" tool of PlugData. I wouldn't actually how to do it otherwise, do you have any suggestions?
